# Retrieve cell value from each row where coulmn name is UserId using SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm trying to get cell value for each row where column name is `UserId` and table name called `NewUsers` and add them to `Dictionary` / `List<T>` / `Array`?

Sorry for missing code I haven't tried.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId,Status FROM NewUsers", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // looking for username and status in database check if is dealer or admin or unknown
            if (reader.Read() || reader.HasRows)
            {
                int i = 0;
                var UserIds = reader["UserId"].ToString();
                foreach (var _userID in UserIds)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(_userID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do it on your own and people will help you if you stop on something.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.  As it stands right now, your post will get downvotes from a lack of effort.

Comment: edited srry for that

Comment: you may need to use `While(reader.read())` for iterating purpose.

Comment: i want to get each cell value from each row where coulmn name UserId
tried what you said its not outpout cell values

Comment: @tuarek you can't display row values if you don't read the rows. That's why you *have* to use `while(reader.read())`. I suspect you should look for an ADO.NET tutorial and understand what a SqlDataReader is and how to read results. Right now you are reading the *same* value over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current approach...

```
List<int> userIds = new List<int>();  //Have to declare your list in which you can store all userid's

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId, Status FROM NewUsers", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                userIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to understand ADO's working, in order to access rows we have to iterate SqlDataReader, so we use while and read untill it finishes all rows. In while loop we have access current row, now we can read column value from the current row and add it to our c# list(userIds) .

Comment: i want to get each cell value from each row where coulmn name UserId

Comment: This isn't a question about DataTables, it's about reading query results. There's no Datatable in the code, nor is it needed

Comment: @tuarek Edited !!

Comment: thank you i understand it better ill read about ADO.net more before asking question

Comment: @PeterB Done...Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

We can clean this up even more:

```
var userIds = new List<int>();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId,Status FROM NewUsers", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            userIds.Add((int)reader["UserId"]);
        }
    }
}
```

I especially want to point out changing the `ToString()` call to an `(int)` cast.

If the database column was already an integer type, then ADO.Net has already handled the conversion to a C# `int`. Calling `ToString()` would convert the integer you already had to a string, and this is a location-aware call so it's a more expensive and complicated process than it seems. Then we convert back again to integer, which again involves a surprisingly complicated and expensive parsing process. *But we already had an integer!*

So just removing that little `ToString()` call can be a surprisingly big win for performance, especially when  we realize we save this work for *every* record in a (potentially large) result set.

Comment: And if you wanted to take it another step further you could do [reader.GetInt32(0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetInt32_System_Int32_) which would bypass the lookup on the ordinal position of the column and also remove the unboxing when the returned `object` is cast back to an `int`. (*sorry about the duplicate comment, I included the wrong link*)